# Why is session variable not being saved after redirect in Chrome only?

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, redirect

In Firefox, the session variable is saved and retrievable after the redirect but in Chrome, after redirect, it says it doesn't exist.

Redirect code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION[ "test" ] = "exists";
session_write_close();
header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); //Removing this 301 line doesn't help
header( "Location: http://" . $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ] . "/" );
exit();
```

Retrieving the session:

```
session_start();
if ( isset( $_SESSION[ "test" ] ) )
{
    echo $_SESSION[ "test" ];
    unset( $_SESSION[ "test" ] );
}
```

Why doesn't this work in chrome?

**EDIT: I think I found the answer but it doesn't make sense.**
If I remove the line `unset( $_SESSION[ "test" ] )` then it saves the session after the redirect! But why does this occur? The session should be server-side. And I unset it after the "echo" statement! How does it not echo the value just because I unset the variable **after** that?!

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Try removing the `header` lines and just let the page die. You should get a blank page, but you may see an error message. If this is the case, what does the error say?

Comment: @Kolink thanks for the response. please see my edit as I found the problem, but it doesn't make sense. It's the `unset( $_SESSION[ "test" ]` line that causes it not to be saved! But I call that after I call echo!

Comment: Might be that Chrome remembers the 301 and therefore never actually runs the code that sets the variable after the very first time. Try removing the 301 and clearing all browser data, does it work afterwards?

Comment: @Jon Just tried that and it doesn't fix it. The 301 isn't the problem. For some reason the "unset" is the problem. But I have no idea why.

Comment: @DonRhummy: I may have the details a bit off, but `unset` is for sure not the problem. Do something observable in your set script, e.g. increment a counter written in a file. Does the counter actually increment each time you hit the "set" URL?

Comment: @Jon it 100% is the problem. Here's what I do: 1. remove the unset variable - google now prints the session variable and says it exists, 2. put unset back in - google again says it does not exist. I repeat this and this is the **only** thing that causes google to ever see the session variable

Comment: @DonRhummy: It's very hard to debug this without having the actual runnable code in hand, but FWIW I repeat: `unset` is not the problem, and [select isn't broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html).

Comment: @Jon I found something else weird: while the `session_write_close();` doesn't help where it is now, if I include **another** call to that after the redirect and right before the `unset( $_SESSION[ "test" ] )` then it saves it after redirect!

Comment: @DonRhummy: No, it doesn't save it. It simply does not unset what has been already saved, since any changes after `session_write_close` do not stick (unless you call `session_start` again). I 've been saying the same thing over and over: you are misreading the observable effects of the code. What actually happens is not what your mental model of what happens is.

Comment: @Jon actually it confirms the issue is the unset! Because stopping the unset from working makes the variable show up again. Even if I do this: `$saved = $_SESSION[ "test" ];` and then call unset after that, in **chrome only** `$saved` will show as empty!

Comment: @Jon, if instead of calling unset, I do this: `$_SESSION[ "test" ] = "another value";` then in chrome even though that new line comes **after** the echo, it will echo "another value". In Firefox it echos "exists"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to multiple requests of the same page by Chrome. No other browser does this the same way so the issue only shows up for Google Chrome.

Comment: Now, I am facing this problem as well. End users lost their login session after payment from another page. May I ask you how did you handle for this problem? This is so confuse for end user if they were logged out after payment.

Comment: @TommyDo I don't remember as it's been 7 years but it had to do with chrome prefetching the page. i think i had to do something to detect that

Answer (score 2):

It may be a problem with the way the redirect is being handled. You're presently telling the browser to redirect offsite (even though we're not really going offsite) by specifying `http://` in the header for location.

```
header( "Location: http://" . $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ] . "/" );
```

If you replace it with this it may help the browser to keep the `SESSION` alive since it believes it is on the same site:

```
header("Location: /");
```

Also, what happens if you do something like this:

```
if (!empty( $_SESSION[ "test" ] ) ){
$test = $_SESSION[ "test" ];
unset( $_SESSION[ "test" ] );

echo $test;
}
```

PHP if I'm not mistaken will perform all server side functions first, then return the code to the user from the print and echo statements.

If I'm right, then that bit of code would work for both of the browsers if it was indeed the unset command that was making the code not work (since we're saving the var to something that can be echoed after the `SESSION` was destroyed.

If it doesn't work, then its a difference in browser session handling more than likely due to the redirect.

**Update**

Also note that 301 redirects can be cached. You're performing these functions on a page that you've already told your browser permanently moved. It may not even be seeing the page that sets the `SESSION` at all if it's relying on the cache on subsequent attempts.

**Update 4/22**

After checking the headers. In the versions of Chrome I'm running (`Version 26.0.1410.64 m` on Windows and `Version 26.0.1410.65` on Mac OS) I do not experience this particular issue. Whether the local URLs vs Offsite URLs are there and regardless of the existence of the `unset()` command.

You can open *Developer Tools* in *Chrome* (Tools > Developer Tools or Ctrl-Shift-i on Windows or Command-Shift-i on Mac) and see the header output under the *Network* tab. There may be something going on with your domain redirecting causing a `SESSION` to be dropped.

It might be specific to a setting on your local machine or your Chrome build for your particular OS (if it's different than my own). Additionally it might be a configuration setting in PHP and how you're actually passing `SESSION`s. I simply pasted your code directly from the question into a new page and created a page for it to redirect to. Upon testing, all of the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE (7,8,9), Opera, Safari, and Mozilla) on my machines say "exists."

Here are my test machine's `SESSION` settings (from `phpinfo()`):
[image: PHP Sessions Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't fix the problem. :(

Comment: With the second one, it says $test is empty. It doesn't print anything.

Comment: Let me dig into the headers. I'll load it and check them out.

Comment: Thank you! Let me know if you need any more info. One thing I discovered: if I create and set a session variable on the page, store it in a local/global variable and then unset the session variable, it works properly. But if the session variable is set on a page that then redirects to the new page and on the new page we store it and then unset the session variable, **that** does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your case is similar to mine. But for me the reason was the formation of URL.

With chrome, when typing the URL as "http://www.domainname.com" and setting the session variables there.

and redirecting with "http://domainname.com" without the **WWW.** the sessionid is not reused.

This resolved my issue hope this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

WE can fix this issue by two way

i . in Firefox browser setting change character Encoding to "UTF-8"

ii . By PHP code at the page add "header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');" which you going to post

Thanks, 
Suresh Ramakrishnan